# npm package.json undocumented keys

Tags: angular, npm, module, ecmascript-6, package.json

I'm seeing some undocumented keys in the package.json in Angular 2/4's source:

```
{
  "name": "@angular/platform-browser/animations",
  "typings": "../animations.d.ts",
  "main": "../bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js",
  "module": "../@angular/platform-browser/animations.es5.js",
  "es2015": "../@angular/platform-browser/animations.js"
}
```

Specifically "modules" and "es2015". I'm finding these all throughout Angular's packages. I'm curious as to how they decide whether to load "main", "modules", or "es2015", specifically because it's always loading "module" (instead of the "es2015" one). Is there a way to force my projects to use the es2015 file from the package.json?

Answer (score 0):

About fields

- `typings` - TypeScript type signatures
- `module` - according to the original proposal, it should point to a module that has `ES2015` module syntax but otherwise only syntax features that the target environments support. Angular for some reason use `.es5` not `es6` aka `ES2015`
- `es2015` - untranspiled ES6 code. Introduced by Angular (do not know any tool which supports it)

See this [repository](https://github.com/stereobooster/package.json) for more information about unofficial package.json fields

> Is there a way to force my projects to use the es2015 file from the package.json?

Not sure which bundler and/or transpiler you are using. If you are using Webpack, you can configure it with `resolve.mainFields`

```
module.exports = {
   resolve: {
       mainFields: ['es2015', 'browser', 'module', 'main'],
   },
   ···
};
```